# VLC Scene Filter for Stream

Tags: stream, video-streaming, vlc

Hi I am receiving a stream on VLC through another PC. The Stream is working on ubuntu 16.04 but I also want to use the scene filter that saves frames to a folder. I am trying to use the scene filter in VLC but it is not working any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.
[Scene filter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LEHJ.png)

Comment: full logs please, "it is not working" is not a good question

Comment: Could you please let me know how should i show you the logs? thanks

Comment: have you googled how to get verbose logs in vlc?

Comment: OK since using VIC was not working i abandoned the idea and went for a different route. Thanks all.